# D3JS different image for each circle/node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So, I want to apply a different image in each circle in d3js.

One circle = one image different to others...

In my JSON data, i add a image path like this :

```
{"name":"Myriel","group":1,"icon": "images/01.png"},
{"name":"Napoleon","group":1,"icon": "images/10.png"}
```

the only solution I found for display images in circles in d3js is :

I declare refs and svg object.

```
for(var i=0;i<graph.nodes.length;i++){

   var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');
            defs.append('svg:pattern')
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .attr('id', "image"+i)
                .attr('width', '1')
                .attr('height', '1')
                .append('svg:image')
                .attr('xlink:href', function(d) { return(graph.nodes[i].icon); })
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 0)
                .attr('width', 120)
                .attr('height', 120);
}
```

and I built my nodes/circles like that :

```
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 30)
      .style("fill","url(#image1)")
      .on("mouseover",function(){

      var sel = d3.select(this)
      sel.moveToFront();
    })
      .on("mouseout",function(){
        var sel = d3.select(this);
          sel.moveToBack();
        });
```

If you want more explication, say me.
Sorry for my english...

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Can you perhaps provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't build a jsfiddle, it's didn't work because data... 
The problem here, I have the same image in all circle, whereas I want different image in each circle..

Comment: Make a minimum reproducible example with your data structure.  If it doesn't work we might be able to help you if we can at least see the entire code.

Comment: i try something, but now, i have only one circle.. http://jsfiddle.net/hn66hpev/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178008/setting-different-images-for-d3-force-directed-layout-nodes

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do it in my project (http://arda-maps.org/familytree/). I'm using **png** as image tough but it very similar if you just replace it with your ID from your svg path.

```
            node
                .append("svg:image")
                .attr("class", "circle")
                .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                    return "/pics/arda/creature/" + d.uniquename + "_familytree.png";
                })
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return familytree.posXY(d);
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return familytree.posXY(d);
                })
                .attr("width", function (d) {
                    return familytree.sizeXY(d);
                })
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                    return familytree.sizeXY(d);
                })
                .on("error", function () {
                    d3.select(this).style("visibility", "hidden");
                });
```

So you should test if this works for you.

```
.attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                    return "url(#image1)";
                })
```